# what does it mean for a matrix to be greater than another?

Tags: matrices, notation

I am reading these notes on viscosity solutions, here is a theorem:

Let us assume $u\in C^2$ is a classical solution of
$F(x,u,Du,D^2u)=0$, $x\in \Omega$

then $u$ is a viscosity solution whenever one of the following two is satsified:

1 The PDE does not depend on $D^2u$

2 $F(x,z,p,M)\leq F(x,z,p,N)$ when $M\geq N$

---

I believe here $M$ and $N$ are Hessian matrices.

My question is what does it mean that a matrix is greater or equal to another?

I remember $M\geq 0$ means it is semi-positive definite, does it mean $M-N$ needs to be semi-positive definite then?

Comment: Yes, exactly. $ $

Comment: It's most likely related to semi-positive definiteness, as you mention. But we'll need to know more about the context to give a definitive answer.

Comment: @Raskolnikov let me add the full statement of the theorem.

Comment: Minor language quibble: I think it is more common to say positive semidefinite than semi-positive definite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the (admittedly quite limited) extent that I know the literature on viscosity solutions, your interpretation is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge, when matrix A is greater than matrix B, it means that A-B is positive definite.